# NodeJS Cluster Mode - Monitor CPU & Memory for each worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, amazon-web-services

I am running Node Application in cluster mode on AWS ec2 instance with 4 CPUs and 7.5 GB of RAM. I would like to monitor CPU and memory for my application. I am more interested in seeing **how is CPU and memory used for each(4 processes) workers**. How can I do this? Any tools I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cpuusage_previousvalue

Answer (score 0):

The best approach was to use `top` or `htop` command on my ubuntu machine to see detailed view of how node application is behaving. I am using `htop` and here below is the view I see. Here I can see 4 processes running and can see individually how CPU and memory is allocated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pm2** for monitoring.

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/monitoring/